# Python requests GET not getting the JSON payload?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to get the JSON data from the following URL:

```
import requests as r

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/json/CorporateFiling/CF-corpactions-equity.json"

header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0',
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
resp = r.get(url, stream=True, timeout=20, headers=header)
j = resp.json()
```

I get the JSON from doing this, but in the inspection I see the data is in the `Response payload` part, which is not in `j`.

I have never faced this problem before and my search lead me to `POST` questions.

Comment: what do you mena when your say "**but in the inspection I see the data is in the Response payload part, which is not in j.**"

Comment: @VishalSingh `len(j)` = 1. It is only picking up the `JSON` and not the `Response payload`.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it using [postman](https://www.postman.com/)

`User-Agent` value is your problem

you could simply remove it and it will work

[image: postman-test-img]

Comment: If I remove `User-Agent` I get a `ReadTimeout` error.

Comment: give a look at the picture I've given you up

Comment: there is another 2 headers

Comment: Oh wow, sorry my mistake. The data just isn't there. Basically have to load a file inside a JS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong and didn't get question correctly, but compering data getting from UI and compering data getting from API are the same:

```
import json
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/json/CorporateFiling/CF-corpactions-equity.json'
header = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0',
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//pre').text
driver.quit()
response = requests.get(url,
                        stream=True,
                        timeout=20,
                        headers=header
                        )
print(json.loads(content) == response.json())
assert json.loads(content) == response.json()
```